# tracks: gem::installerror

Tags: ruby, rvm, bundle

I have a problem installing gems for tracks. I performed the following steps:
Installation of rvm:

```
bash < <(curl -sk https://raw.github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/master/binscripts/rvm-installer)
echo '[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"' >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
```

Installation of ruby:

```
rvm install ruby-1.8.7
rvm use ruby-1.8.7 --default
ruby -v
```

Last command responds:

```
ruby 1.8.7 (2012-02-08 patchlevel 358) [x86_64-linux]
```

Git clone of tracks:

```
git clone https://github.com/TracksApp/tracks.git
cd tracks
nano backup.rails2.3/Gemfile.rails2.3
```

Changes made in this flie:
 - comment out gem "sqlite3"
 - change gem "ZenTest", "=4.6.0"

After this i performed bundle install which exits with the following error:

```
Gem::InstallError: factory_girl requires Ruby version >= 1.9.2.
An error occured while installing factory_girl (3.3.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install factory_girl -v '3.3.0'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Tracks does not support ruby 1.9.x so version upgrade is not possible. How can I fix above mentioned problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have cloned deveopment version which seams be getting ready for Ruby 1.9: 
https://github.com/TracksApp/tracks/blob/master/Gemfile#L51

Either use it with ruby 1.9 or use older version:
https://github.com/TracksApp/tracks/tags

Comment: This solved it! Used guide https://github.com/TracksApp/tracks/wiki/Installing-Tracks-2.0-on-Ubuntu-12.04-%28rvm%29 mentions the dev version.